# What's the regex to match a string except it has a $ dollar sign in it?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So basically, I have a text like this:

```
secret(mapOf("path" to "config/info"))
secret(mapOf("path" to "config/data/${rootProject.name}"))
prefix(mapOf("path" to "config/${rootProject.name}", "format" to "${rootProject.name.replace('-', '_')}"))
```

I want to match a path like `config/info` and not to match paths which contain variables (have dollar signs in them). I came up with this `((?:'|\")config/.+(?:'|\"))` but it also matches the others. 
How can I exclude strings with dollar signs?

Comment: `^[^$]+$` may be?

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include a few examples of strings you want to accept and strings you want to reject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for (if I fully understand your question) is this one:

```
(['\"]config/[^$]+['\"])
```

**Explanation:**

- I used `['"]` instead of `(?:'|\")` I believe it will make your regex
  readable and simple to understand in the future.
- Also using `[^$]+` instead of `.+` is the key to solve your issue, `.+` will match anything however `[^$]+` will match anything as long as it's not `$`.